# how to remove the elements of some elements of particular indies from both the lists?

Tags: python, list

I have got 2 lists

```
dt_dates= [datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0)]

param=['14', '8', '24', '21.5', '28.5', '9', '9.5', '14.5', '5.5', '21', '19', '25', '25', '18', '12', '32']
```

I have a code that filters the list according to end date and start date. Say a user enters a date range from `1/1/2014` to `12/31/2014` then I need all the dates t hat falls between the range and the parameters for the remaining dates.

```
dt_dates_filtered= [datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 0, 0)]
```

is the desired output

```
parameters_filtered=['14.5', '5.5', '21', '19', '25', '25']
```

I wrote the code:

```
for i,v in enumerate (dt_dates):
    if t1[i]:
        filtered_parameter.append(param[i])
```

whiere t1 is the dates between start date and end date

Comment: You should post whatever you have tried, SO is not a code-writing service. And if you are stuck at something, we can help you with that.

Comment: I had written a code :
for i,v in enumerate (dt_dates):
    if t1[i]:
        r1.append(r[i])
but its ot not throughing out the desired values

Comment: done.. can you do it now?

Comment: the elements of list t1 ie t1= [datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 0, 0)]

Comment: does tthis look ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrongly, you should iterate over both of them together and create the lists you want.

You can use `zip` function for this.

Example -

```
dt_dates= [datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0)]
param=['14', '8', '24', '21.5', '28.5', '9', '9.5', '14.5', '5.5', '21', '19', '25', '25', '18', '12', '32']

dt_dates_filtered= []
parameters_filtered=[]

start_date = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1,0,0,0)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2014,12,31,0,0,0)

for x in zip(dt_dates, param):
    if start_date < x[0] < end_date:
            dt_dates_filtered.append(x[0])
            parameters_filtered.append(x[1])

dt_dates_filtered
>>> [datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 0, 0)]
parameters_filtered
>>> ['14.5', '5.5', '21', '19', '25', '25']
```